# Getting variable type and variable info from Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#

Basically I'm trying to make it so I can do

```
Console.WriteLine("variable : value");
var stuff = Console.ReadLine();
```

And then use the first word of "stuff" to be the variable type int,string etc. and the rest of the line to be what the variable's value is, so like

string testing this

would make a variable i made into a string and the value be "testing this"

Comment: Can you please elaborate why do you need this? There can be better ways to achieve your purpose.

Comment: I'm using it for a bot in a chat system that has channels, I was just thinking of another way to do it that would generate the same goal if I change some things. I'm trying to make it so I can say in the console the channel name and then the message, i.e chat hello guys.

I know how to get channels and messages, but the only issue is splitting the Console.ReadLine()

Comment: `stuff.GetType()` would return System.String...  is that good enough, or do you really need it to say just string?

Comment: I just need it to be a string, the first value, but I'm trying to basically remove the first word, and use it somewhere else, maybe that should have been the question.

Comment: `Console.ReadLine` _always_ returns a string.  Sure, you can split a string into multiple, smaller strings and parse a string into another type, but when you don't know your destination type things get messy quick.  So yes, it can be done but it seems like you're heading down a dirty road.  Maybe if you gave concrete examples of what you want to _do_ with that information a better answer could be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string stuff = Console.ReadLine(); // get the input in string
string[] stuffSplit = stuff.Split(' '); // split by space char
string firstStuff = stuffSplit[0]; // the first word
string theRestOfStuff = string.Join(" ", stuffSplit.Skip(1)); // the rest of the words combined with space again
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int integerNumber;
            double doubleNumber;
            var stuff = Console.ReadLine();
            bool isInteger = int.TryParse(stuff, out integerNumber);
            bool isDouble = double.TryParse(stuff, out doubleNumber);
            if(isInteger)
                Console.WriteLine(integerNumber.GetType() + stuff);
            else if(isDouble)
                Console.WriteLine(doubleNumber.GetType() + stuff);
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(stuff.GetType() + stuff );
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

You get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var inputText = Console.ReadLine();
string stuff = string.Empty;
if(inputText != null && inputText.IndexOf(':') > 0)
{
    stuff = inputText.Substring(inputText.IndexOf(':')+2, inputText.Length)
}
```